# Render HTML to image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

**Before anybody marks this as dupe :), this is not a dupe, none of the solutions on SO seem to work anymore...**

I have HTML, want to display it in a WPF UI and have the same issues as everybody else:

1) the WebBrowser control doesn't play nice in the WPF world and doesn't clip, goes out of bounds, etc.

2) WebBrowser control can't render to a bitmap to fix problem #1

3) I tried HTMLRenderer in both the HtmlPanel and HtmlRenderer.RenderToImage and neither work. I ended up with a garbled mess.

Any solutions that work in 2017? NOTE: My test HTML renders fine in IE, the WebBrowser control and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If it renders in IE you should set the Browser Emulation value to 11000 for your application. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation